# Is it possible in Python to call a child from parent class without initialize the child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, class-hierarchy

I want to know if is it possible to create a parent class to handle some common logic, but have some specific logic in child classes and run it without initialize the child as it's in abstraction.

For example:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, fname, lname, country):
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname
    self.country = country

    if country == "US":
      # Call class UnitedStates(Person)
    else if country == "CA":
      # Call class Canada(Person)

  def printCountry(self):
    print(self.firstname + " " + self.lastname + " is from " + self.country)

class UnitedStates(Person):
  def __init__(self):
    super().country="United States"
    pass

class Canada(Person):
  def __init__(self):
    super().country="Canada"
    pass

x = Person("John", "Doe", "US")
x.printCountry()

y = Person("Jane", "Doe", "CA")
y.printCountry()
```

So in x I have "John Doe is from United States" and in y I have "Jane Doe is from Canada".

The reason I need that come from a high complex logic and that's the easiest way to deal, so that sample is a dummy version of what I need, otherwise I'll need to find the best way for a "work around".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want you can have a factory method in your parent class that creates the appropriate child class. It won't be an `__init__` method, though, it will just be a normal method. (I think. Python lets you do anything, so it might let you have a constructor that returns a different type, but it will make the eyes of anyone who reads it bleed.)

Comment: Looking at this more, I think you should add some clarity on what you're trying to do. I think you may be confusing ownership with inheritance, which are independent concepts. A `Person` can own a reference to a country without extending that country. Do you really want a `Canada` to *be* a `Person`?